# zScaler proxy: ZAP Error [java.net.SocketException]: Connection reset

Tags: owasp, zap, zscaler

I use ZAP behind a zScaler corporate proxy.
http traffic works fine, but if I want to access any website via https:// I get the following exception:

```
ZAP Error [java.net.SocketException]: Connection reset


Stack Trace:
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:323)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:966)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:484)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:478)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:160)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1510)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1425)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.executeHandshake(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:303)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:275)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:251)
    at org.zaproxy.addon.network.internal.client.apachev5.SslConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SslConnectionSocketFactory.java:195)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:181)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.ZapHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(ZapHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:95)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:433)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalExecRuntime.connectEndpoint(InternalExecRuntime.java:159)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalExecRuntime.connectEndpoint(InternalExecRuntime.java:169)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ConnectExec.execute(ConnectExec.java:146)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:192)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ZapHttpRequestRetryExec.execute(ZapHttpRequestRetryExec.java:81)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ZapInternalHttpClient.doExecute(ZapInternalHttpClient.java:158)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:245)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:188)
    at org.zaproxy.addon.network.internal.client.apachev5.HttpSenderApache.sendImpl0(HttpSenderApache.java:394)
    at org.zaproxy.addon.network.internal.client.apachev5.HttpSenderApache.sendImpl(HttpSenderApache.java:297)
    at org.zaproxy.addon.network.internal.client.apachev5.HttpSenderApache.sendImpl(HttpSenderApache.java:103)
    at org.zaproxy.addon.network.internal.client.BaseHttpSender.sendAuthenticated(BaseHttpSender.java:298)
    at org.zaproxy.addon.network.internal.client.BaseHttpSender.sendNoRedirections(BaseHttpSender.java:266)
    at org.zaproxy.addon.network.internal.client.BaseHttpSender.send(BaseHttpSender.java:222)
    at org.zaproxy.addon.network.internal.client.BaseHttpSender.sendAndReceive(BaseHttpSender.java:193)
    at org.zaproxy.addon.network.internal.client.BaseHttpSender.sendAndReceive(BaseHttpSender.java:57)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.sendAndReceive(HttpSender.java:303)
    at org.zaproxy.addon.network.internal.server.http.handlers.HttpSenderHandler.handleMessage(HttpSenderHandler.java:77)
    at org.zaproxy.addon.network.internal.server.http.MainServerHandler.notifyMessageHandlers(MainServerHandler.java:133)
    at org.zaproxy.addon.network.internal.server.http.MainServerHandler.processMessage(MainServerHandler.java:115)
    at org.zaproxy.addon.network.internal.server.http.LocalServerHandler.processMessage(LocalServerHandler.java:63)
    at org.zaproxy.addon.network.internal.server.http.MainServerHandler.process(MainServerHandler.java:84)
    at org.zaproxy.addon.network.internal.server.http.MainServerHandler.channelRead0(MainServerHandler.java:73)
    at org.zaproxy.addon.network.internal.server.http.MainServerHandler.channelRead0(MainServerHandler.java:38)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$600(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:61)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$7.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:370)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor.run(DefaultEventExecutor.java:66)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Using curl with the proxy works fine:

```
C:\Users\ORI17635>curl -v https://google.de
* Uses proxy env variable all_proxy == 'http://165.225.72.40:80'
*   Trying 165.225.72.40:80...
* Connected to 165.225.72.40 (165.225.72.40) port 80 (#0)
* allocate connect buffer
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to google.de:443
> CONNECT google.de:443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: google.de:443
> User-Agent: curl/8.0.1
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established
< Proxy-Agent: Zscaler/6.2
<
* CONNECT phase completed
* CONNECT tunnel established, response 200
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* ALPN: offers http/1.1
* ALPN: server accepted http/1.1
* using HTTP/1.1
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: google.de
> User-Agent: curl/8.0.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Location: https://www.google.de/
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: object-src 'none';base-uri 'self';script-src 'nonce-aSS9KPWBUfr_W55RxLWlGw' 'strict-dynamic' 'report-sample' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https: http:;report-uri https://csp.withgoogle.com/csp/gws/other-hp
< Date: Mon, 17 Jul 2023 21:27:35 GMT
< Expires: Mon, 17 Jul 2023 21:27:35 GMT
< Cache-Control: private, max-age=2592000
< Server: gws
< Content-Length: 219
< X-XSS-Protection: 0
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
...
```

I tried with a selfsigned root certificate.
But I guess the problem is that ZAP sets "Zed Attack Proxy Project" as organisation unit when replacing the server certificate.

Comment: Did you set the zscaler as the upstream proxy in ZAP? https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/addons/network/options/connection/#http-proxy

Comment: @kingthorin yes, upstream proxy (bypassed for hosts in my local network)

Comment: Which version of ZAP are you using? Based on the stack trae it does not look like you are using the latest version. I'd strongly recommend you update to using the latest version (currently 2.13.0) as that has a number of potentially related fixes.

Comment: @SimonBennetts Thanks, I am using using 2.12.0. I'll try to get an update (can take a while in corporate environments :-)